# jquery parameter offsetY not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, sidebar

Im using a jquery plugin stickyfloat to create a floating sidebar on my webpage.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neo3000ultra/vkvvX/

By default, the sidebar appears at the top right corner of its parent container, I want the sidebar to stay at the right bottom corner of the container, so I gave it an `offsetY` parameter according to its documentation.

```
$('#menu').stickyfloat({offsetY: 500});
```

But not matter how I change the value of the `offsetY`parameter, the position of the sidebar does not change. It seems that that parameter is not working.

So can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in the 'stickToBottom' parameter:

```
$('#menu').stickyfloat({stickToBottom: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the stickyfloat code? you can probably find some width or position parameter to change..

Answer (score 1):

there was a bug, now it works fine, check it out:

http://dropthebit.com/74/sticky-floating-box/